# Does a bounded convex domain has one smooth boundary point?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, several-complex-variables

In the study of analysis and geometry of a bounded domain, its boundary regularity is important. For example, it is known that a bounded convex domain has Lipschitz bounday. This implies that a bounded convex domain in the complex Euclidean space $\mathbb C^n$ has to be hyperconvex, namely, it admits a bounded exhaustive plurisubharmonic function.

My question concerns stronger regularity of the boundary of a convex domain, which can be fomulated as: does a convex domain has one smooth boundary point? comparing to the whole boundary, how large is the set of smooth boundary points?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Convex functions are twice differentiable almost everywhere, see e.g. http://people.math.sc.edu/howard/Notes/alex.pdf.

Comment: @Igor: Thanks! I am still not so clear. Try to represent a convex domain as $\{x|f(x)<0\}$, where $f$ is a convex function. How can we see that $D$ has smooth boundary points from the statement that convex functions are twice differentiable almost everywhere? Note that the boundary of $D$ has measure 0 in general.

Comment: The graph of a smooth function is smooth. I suggest you read some textbook on the subject, e.g. Schneider in "Convex bodies: Brunn-Minkowski theory", 2nd edition devotes a whole chapter to boundary regularity, and the result I mentioned above is Theorem 2.61.

Comment: To return to the original question, there need not be a *smooth* (as in $C^{\infty}$) boundary point, of course. You can just start with a negative nowhere differentiable (and, let's say, continuous) function and integrate it twice to produce a convex function that isn't smooth anywhere.

Comment: @Christian Yes, thanks! So we can just expect $C^2$ bounday points.

Comment: @Entaou: twice differentiable is weaker than $C^2$.

Comment: @Igor:  sounds not so good! So it is possible that a convex domain has no $C^2$  boundary point.

Comment: Take an atomic measure $\mu$ that has full support (for example a mass $1/q^{2+\delta}$ on every rational $p/q$) and integrate it up twice. This is convex, but nowhere $C^2$. (Not even $C^1$ in any interval...) Furthermore, the second derivative is zero wherever it exists, so it doesn't contain much information.

Comment: @Martin Oh yes, it is mentioned in the book suggested by Igor that generic convex sets has no $C^2$ boundary points. It seems that except Lipschitz we can not say a lot interesting about the boundary of a general convex set.